# JsonSerializationException: Unexpected end when deserializing array

Tags: c#, json, azure, asp.net-web-api

i'm getting problems with deserialization.
I heaven don't know if include entities is possible in server side. I have this includes in Client side but for that i was not using the get service.

**WebAPI Controller**

```
// GET: api/UnidadeCurricular
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<UnidadeCurricular> GetUnidadeCurricular()
{
    return _context.UnidadeCurricular.Include(c => c.Departamento)
    .Include(c => c.Curso)
    .Include(c => c.NomeUC)
    .ToList();
}
```

**WebApp Controller**

```
// GET: Unidade_curriculares
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    List<UnidadeCurricular> unidade_curricular = new List<UnidadeCurricular>();
    string path = "api/UnidadeCurricular";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpRequestBuilder.WebApiClient.GetAsync(path);

    //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        unidade_curricular = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<UnidadeCurricular>>();
    }

    return View(unidade_curricular);
}
```

**Erro** https://i.stack.imgur.com/bygnF.png

Hi want to get the information about the FK's that i have in this table and for that i just include the other in the context but when the service is call the error shows and i can't understand why it stops the desirialization.

Comment: Have you tried to get a response as string to analyze?

Comment: It simple crashes on the includes in the get service

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: The error is showed in the url... The deserialization stops when the method try to include the other entites but i don't know why and heave if it's possible to include on the server side